# I want to play two sounds in background one after another in android

Tags: android, audio

```
dogIntroSound =  MediaPlayer.create(AnimalPiker1.this, R.raw.introdog);
dogIntroSound.start();

Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            dogSound =  MediaPlayer.create(AnimalPiker1.this, R.raw.dog);
            dogSound.start();

        }
    }
};

timer.start();
```

**I have tried lots of things but this is most recent but this is even not working**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setOnCompletionListener:

```
dogIntroSound =  MediaPlayer.create(AnimalPiker1.this, R.raw.introdog);
dogIntroSound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
     dogSound =  MediaPlayer.create(AnimalPiker1.this, R.raw.dog);
     dogSound.start();
   }

});

dogIntroSound.start();
```